# Words in all capitals not allowed in Facebook page name?

Tags: facebook-pages

Having an issue getting the word "IT" displayed as "IT" and not "It" in a Facebook Company Page.

Basically, they don't allow block capitals or "shouting" page titles and contacting them gets nowhere.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

They do allow capitals.
If you have more than 100 fans then you cannot change it.

If you are talking about the username, the same thing applies.
Once you have selected a username, you cannot change it.

*As it says, it sounds like you hit a filter that prevents fake pages from being made. Your only option from this point on is to wait for a reply from Facebook. Don't try to delete your page, that would just make things more difficult*

Comment: Yes, they will allow a page name such as "Blah It" though when trying to change the page name to something such as "Blah IT" it fails with this message: Our automated system will not allow that name, consider "Bleh It"

Comment: As it says, it sounds like you hit a filter that prevents fake pages from being made. Your only option from this point on is to wait for a reply from Facebook. Don't try to delete your page, that would just make things more difficult.